# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill not maintaining aspect ratio of image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using `UIImageView` in `UICollectionViewCell`. I have set `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` and `Clip subviews` to `YES`.

[image]

Still image's aspect ratio is not maintained. It shrinks image width/height.

Please note that I know I can center crop image through code but I am looking for a way to do it without using code to change image size.
Also I can't use `UIViewContentModeCenter` because real image is much larger than `UIImageView` size.

Answer (score -2):

For maintaining Aspect Ratio you have to use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit instead of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

Comment: Both maintains aspect ratio.

Comment: but if image size is less than the imageView size.